# How can I stop IntelliJ IDEA printing an empty new line?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am following the Atomic Kotlin course. I have understood the concept and my output is correct, however Intellij IDEA complains that the outputs are different. Even when I copy and paste from the answer. Please see screenshot. [image: incorrect output]

I have tried using the `print()` method instead of `println()`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Settings->Editor->General` and uncheck the `Ensure an empty line..` property.

see the following screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a straightforward workaround on how one can avoid this problem. Changing the `AtomicKotlin/Programming Basics/Data Types/Exercise 2/test/output.txt` manually to add a new line at the end of the text should fix the test.
I've also found a [YouTrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/EDU-3525) with the problem description. According to it, EduTools 4.2 version release should fix it. Maybe it worth to upvote or comment on the ticket.